# Best Approach to do decoupling of large & small code in existing trunk & create new trunk with current code

Tags: svn, build, trunk

I have got a trunk with has got code of (release 2 + release 1), currently release 2 is in development phase. Unfortunately customer has decided not to take release 1 content/code. So some action points came to us.

1. How to get rid of release 1 content on trunk
2. I want to keep the release 1 content for future usage, may be customer would ask it for future.
3. **Approach**:
   As the release 1 code is large and release 2 development has just started so to do the decoupling we have decided to create a new feature branch (FB_release1) which will be replica of trunk and then release 2 code from feature branch (FB_release1) will be merged/override to existing trunk.

   - what are the consequences in this approach?
   - any other simpler approach?